# Strange result using Array.reduce

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, reduce

I'm trying to merge array of JSON objects to one object using jQuery.extend function. 
Assume, i have a sample array:

```
arr = [{a:4},{b:5}];
```

in case:

```
arr.reduce( $.extend  ) 
//result { "1":{b:5}, a:4, b:5 }
```

but

```
arr.reduce( function( a, b){ return $.extend(a,b) } );
//is ok: { a:4, b:5 }
```

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function passed to `reduce` will receive four arguments (the last two are the index of the current item and the array that `reduce` was called on). You're only interested in the first two, but `jQuery.extend` takes a variable number of arguments, so it slurps them all up. By explicitly writing a function that takes two arguments and passes them to `extend`, you avoid this and get the behavior you expected.

Answer (score 1):

The result seems strange only until you see the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility) implementation, particularly this statement before the loop begins:

```
if(arguments.length <= 1) {  
  curr = this[0]; // Increase i to start searching the secondly defined element in the array  
  i = 1; // start accumulating at the second element  
}
```

Makes sense now.  And `extend` is dynamic in nature so it will take everything you give it (not just the two arguments you really want).

Comment: I disagree with you ..

You're writing about case  if i wanted define initial value of reduce as:

`[1,2,3].reduce(fn , init_val )` 

Note that the  reduce function gets always( in my sample ) one argument that is function... Look at my answer.